# Qt how to write to HKLM

Tags: c++, qt, registry

In my Qt5.5 app I'm trying to write to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

registry key, to enable autorun on every account, using QSettings, but I can't do it even with Administrator Priviliges. Could you tell me how should I do it right way? If I try to use this code with HKCU to enable autorun to current user, it's working.

```
QSettings bootUp("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", QSettings::NativeFormat);
bootUp.setValue("/MyApp", "\"" + QDir::currentPath() + "/MyApp.exe\"" + " -a -u");
```

Comment: Note that a better solution is to add a shortcut to your application in the Start Menu's "Startup" folder. That can be done for either a specific user or for all users. Leave the registry alone.

Comment: Is it the exact code that you are running? Could you provide your working code for `HKCU` too to compare?

Comment: @John_West I've only replaced HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and new key is not showing.

Comment: @CodyGray How does one switch between current user and all users? I've read of some `AllUsers`-setting supporting `true` and `false`, but can't find anything in the docs on how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510656/how-to-distinguish-per-user-vs-system-wide-installation-in-qt-installer-framewo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's confusing you is that you have a 32 bit process running on 64 bit Windows and you are writing to a part of the registry that is redirected by the [registry redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). So

```
HKLM\Software
```

is redirected to

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node
```

You'll find your entries under there. This is nothing to worry about. The system will reads keys from both 32 and 64 views on startup.

Remember that if your code was failing to write to the registry then it would be throwing an exception.

In short, your code works, you are just looking in the wrong place in the Registry Editor.

Comment: @Ilya that's a little different because virtualization is involved there. I'm assuming that we aren't virtualized here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it's true, this key really exists... My problem is solved :) Thank you.

Comment: Your psychic debugging skills are better than mine. Last time I remember looking at it, Qt didn't use exceptions (has that changed?) and that QSettings::setValue method returns void, so there seemed to be little chance of an error getting reported if one were to occur.

Comment: @Cody I don't know Qt. I just assume it throws.